# Back button fires as soon as page loads

Tags: javascript, browser-history

Here is the code for the back button I'm trying to include at the top of my page:

```
<a onClick={this.goBack()}>Go back</a>
```

And here is the helper function goBack():

```
  goBack(){
    return history.go(-1);
  }
```

I've also tried this, which produces the same result:

```
<a href={this.goBack()}>Go back</a>
```

I'm new to the history method, so any clarification would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back()">Go back</a>
```

Comment: I tried this solution inside my React component, but couldn't get it to work.

<a href="#" onClick={window.history.back()}>Go back</a>

Comment: get rid of the {}
 <a href="#" onClick="window.history.back()">Go back</a>

Answer (score 1):

`this.goBack()` immediately executes function `this.goBack`.

Instead, only assign the function as an event handler by removing the brackets `()`:

```
<a onClick={this.goBack}>Go back</a>
```

Comment: Ahhhh. Yes, that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.